# Futures in Vertx

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I have a scenario where I get the `List<Future<String>>` from Handlers and now have to return `Future<List<String>>`.
 Why the output is always empty though I am checking on all futures once completed.

```
Future<List<String>> output = Future.future();
List futures =
    services.entrySet().stream()
        .map(
            entry -> {
              Future future = Future.future();
              webClient
                  .getAbs(entry.getKey())
                  .timeout(1000)
                  .send(
                      ar -> {
                        if (ar.succeeded()) {
                          if (ar.result().statusCode() == HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()) {
                            services.put(entry.getKey(), "OK");
                            future.complete(entry.getKey());
                          }
                        } else {
                          services.put(entry.getKey(), "Failed");
                          future.fail(ar.cause());
                        }
                      });
              return future;
            })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

CompositeFuture.join(futures)
    .setHandler(
        ar -> {
          futures.forEach(
              fut -> {
                okServices.add(fut.toString());
              });
        });
output.complete(okServices);
System.out.println(output.result());
return output;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you meant but Future of List should be implemented via `CompositeFuture` https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_async_coordination

I would put your code like that:

```
List<Future<String>> futures = services.entrySet().stream().map( entry -> { 
  Future future = Future.future(); 
  WebClient.getAbs(entry.getKey()).send( future ); 
  return future;
} ).collect(toList);

CompositeFuture.join(futures).onComplete(ar -> {
  futures.forEach( fut -> {
    if (fut.succeeded()) {
      log.info( "succeeded " + fut );
    } else {
      log.warn( "failed " + fut );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use CompositeFuture because I want to get the result of the individual future and save it for the further use. Once I get the List<Future<String>> I want to convert that into Future<List<String>>

Comment: You still can get the results of each individual feature of your list, when the composite future ends

Comment: for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : services.entrySet()) {
      Future future = Future.future();
      WebClient
          .getAbs(entry.getKey())
          .send(
              ar -> {
                if (ar.succeeded() && ar.result().statusCode() == 200) {
                  future.complete(ar.result());
                
                } else {
                  futures.add("Failed");
                }
              });
    }
What are your thoughts about this as each handler will do it asynchronously and we can just get the future once completed and then add to list.

Comment: This works like a charm, I just have one question, why futures is printed as empty outside for loop even though we add failed when response code is not 200.

Comment: You may want to fill your futures with response data `WebClient.send( ar -> { fut.complete( ar.result().bodyAsString() ) } )` method, more what you had originally

Comment: see update                                                                                                                       I get your point but I want to return a Future<List<String>> and don't know when I try to call this method using handler gives me an empty list.

Comment: no, that's not going to work. In this case you a returning a completed future with a list of not yet completed futures. I don't see any other nice way than using a composite future at some point.

Comment: I get your point, I cannot find any onComplete method for CompositeFuture in Vertx, have they changed this method with any other?

Comment: in 3.8.5 you can use either `onComplete` or `setHandler`, in older versions only `setHanlder`

Comment: Thanks a ton, `i am left with last bit, would be great if you can advise.

Comment: The output is always empty though I check on each future once completed and also the list of future is giving me correct result but once use Future.complete(List<String>) it prints empty

Comment: `CompsiteFuture.join()` is an async call, so it's too early to return something immediately after it. You should define callback (another Future or AsyncResult) and call it from inside  `CompositeFuture.setHandler()` method. This is also exactly the right place to print your `output` out